# UIBlurEffect view does not cover the background image

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiblureffect

I used very simple code in viewDidLoad function to create a blur effect above an imageView which has the content view of an image.

But somehow the very strange result comes out that the blur view did not cover the image View. The funny thing is that this phenonmenon only happens in the simulator iPhone 6 and the real device iPhone 6.

Here is the picture showing the code and the result:
[image]

Comment: in iphone 4, 5 and so on, it works just fine. I really want to know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue myself before. Call:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

before super.viewDidLoad() and after setting the blur

Comment: Hi, I used this line of code  before super.viewDidLoad() , but the it does not make any sense for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You need to put it before super.viewDidLoad() and after setting your blur

Comment: I tried adding this code also after setting the blur, but it still does not work. Finally I found the only solution for me is to set blurView.frame = self.view.bounds